# How to write to stdout like a file object in python

Tags: python-3.x, stdout

Working on python script that uses `stdin` and `stdout`. The default
behaviour is the script will write to a file, so I have this function
that is called to handle writing to a file:

```py
def run_loop(data,name):
    with open(name, 'w') as fo:
        fo.write("webstat output "+t) # t is a date str created in global scope
        for x in data:
            fo.write(processer(x))
        fo.write('\n')
```

I have a few places in the script where I use this function, so it
would be less convenient to have to rewrite it or write a substituent
of it to work with stdout. When I try using stdout with open,
sys.stdout says its a type `_io.TextIOWrapper`. I get an error when
tying to call `run_loop(same_data,sys.stdout)` I get this error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

I'm wondering if there is away to use `open()` with `stdout`? I would
guess that since `stdout` is file io, I should be able to write to it as
a file. Ideally there would be a way to change `_io.TextIOWrapper` into
an object that `open()` can use, but I've been looking at types of the
methods inside of `sys.stdout` and they don't seem to provide this
facility. I'm not sure why the `fo` object from `open()` couldn't be
set to `stdout`?

The behaviour I'm trying to achieve is

```sh
cat input-data.txt | myscript.py > out.txt
```

I've been able to get the `stdin` portion to work, but I'm still at a
loss for how to write to `stdout` with `open()`.

Supposedly, I could forego `open()`, if I could keep compatibility with
the other places I call this function: `data` being a list and `name`
usually being a string of the file name where the output should be saved.

---

Python 3.7.5rc1

Comment: If the behavior you want is `myscript.py > out.txt` why ever write to a file? Just print everything to std out. If you want to always write to a file then take in the filename as a command line argument so `myscript.py out.txt`. Otherwise you will need to write code to handle the two cases separately as you cannot open stdout like a file. Alternatively you can write to a file, then print the contents of the file to stdout afterward, and subsequently delete the file.

Comment: @illiteratecoder >I have a few places in the script where I use this function, so it would be less convenient to have to rewrite it or write a substituent of it to work with stdout. there are a few modes of operation that this script does.

Comment: @illiteratecoder Because that is an example and I might want to send the scripts output to another program.